# Which one is appropriate: much or many?

Tags: quantifiers

Should one say: "She knows much more people than me" or "many more people than me?"

Comment: Strictly speaking I think only ***many*** is "correct" in your exact context (because ***people*** is an "uncountable, mass noun", as in *She has much more **money** than me*, not a normal "countable" noun as in *She has many more **siblings** than me*). But in practice I wouldn't call it a serious error to get this one wrong - many native speakers might make the same or similar "mistakes", and I'm sure there will be at least some contexts where ***much more*** and ***many more*** are both considered "acceptable" and equivalent by many native speakers.

Comment: (...in which context it's worth noting that [***fewer and fewer***](http://www.grammarerrors.com/grammar/lessfewer/) people take any notice of grammarians arguing over the acceptability of ***less and less*** people. So don't spend too much time on this issue; it's as much about pedantry as it is about actual usage and/or useful grammatical principles.)

Answer (score 1):

"People" is here functioning as a plural noun, and so it is countable. "*Many more people than me*" is undoubtedly correct.  Sometimes you will hear "much" being used with countable nouns, but some people consider this to be an error. However, both "much" and "many" would be understood in this context.